# How can i convert class component object to functional component object in React?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Below is an object array used in class component.

```
const columns = [
{
 title: 'Name',
 dataIndex: 'name',
 key: 'name',
 render: text => <a>{text}</a>
},
{
 title: 'Tags',
 key: 'tags',
 dataIndex: 'tags',
 render: tags => (
  <span>
    {tags.map(tag => {
      let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
      if (tag === 'loser') {
        color = 'volcano';
      }
      return (
        <Tag color={color} key={tag}>
          {tag.toUpperCase()}
        </Tag>
      );
    })}
  </span>
  )
 },
];
```

this is a column array of a table. Since i'm using functional component i replaced the render to return. But i'm not getting the expected behavior in the UI
Can anyone correct me?
I'm using "antd":"3.26.18" library

functional component is

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Table, Button, Tag} from 'antd';
const myComp = () => {
    const columns = getColumns();
    const dataSource = getTableData(rowData);

    return (
    <Table
        data-testid={'results-grid'}
        className="searchResultsTable"
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        />
  )
}
```

Comment: could you show your functional component?

Comment: added my funct component